# Using a private attribute of an array of objects at a logical ecpression in an other class (Array of objects and static/non-static methods)

Tags: java, arrays, object

Array of objects and static/non-static methods.

```
class Foititis      //Dimiourgeia twn antikeimenwn typou foititis
    {
        private String onoma, epitheto;
        private short AriMit, EtosEis;
        public Foititis (String on, String ep, short AM, short EE)
            {
                onoma = on;
                epitheto = ep;
                AriMit = AM;
                EtosEis = EE;
            }

        public String getEpwnymo()      //Prosbash sto epitheto apo tis alles klaseis
            {
                return epitheto;
            }
        public String toString()
            {
                String emf;
                emf = "--------------------" + "\n";
                emf = "Onoma" + onoma + "\n";
                emf = "Epwnymo" + epitheto + "\n";
                emf = "Arithmos Mitrwoy" + AriMit + "\n";
                emf = "Etos Eisagwnis" + EtosEis + "\n";
                emf = "--------------------";
                return emf;
            }


    }

class MyUtils01     //Anazitisi Me Epwnymo, Seiriaki Anazitisi
    {
        public static int AnazitisiMeEpwnymo(Foititis[] a, String key)
            {
                boolean flag = false;
                int j = 0;
                return -1;
                while ( !flag && j < a.length)
                    {
                        if (a[j].getEpwnymo.equals(key))
                            {
                                flag = true;
                                return j;
                            }
                        j += 1;
                    }
            }
    }
```

At this program, I have an array (named pinakas) and sent to the method "AnazitisiMeEpwnymo" of the class "MyUtils01", and renamed "a" (in order to be used). The array is an array of objects of the type "Foititis". So I want to have access from the class "MyUtils01" at the attribute "epitheto", which is private, that's why I tried to use a get method, but I get an [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvDvC.jpg) message.

Thank you in advance, I know that my thread may be covered somehow at another post, but none (from those that I found) where not using array of objects, and did not try to call the method like above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing some parentheses

```
a[j].getEpwnymo().equals(key)
               ^^
```

not

```
a[j].getEpwnymo.equals(key)
```

Comment: Aww, I was not aware that I needed them even there, because (for me) this type of calling the method did not seem like like the "traditional" one. But now I am missing the return statement, this is the compile error.

Comment: Also, I was getting a compile error that my if statement was unreachable, so I changed it from         
`if (pinakas1[j].getEpwnymo().equals(key))` to
 `if (pinakas1[j].getEpwnymo().equals(key) == true)` and it is accepted now. Why is that? isn't "equal" supposed to be a boolean statement? So if it returns true if will be executed if not then it won't.